# Getting a pointer to a variable in a union

Tags: c++, unions

I was just wondering if this is the correct syntax for a pointer to a char in a union:

```
union myunion {
char character[4];
}

... = &(myunion.character[0])
```

It seems to produce the correct result in my application and I can't seem to find the correct syntax on the internet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably mean "It doesn't seem to produce the correct result"? Besides, what is the result vs. the expected result? Does it compile? Is it that what you get from the pointer is not what you expected?

Comment: I do mean "it seems to produce the correct result" - I just want to make sure it isn't doing something unexpected.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the question. The above won't compile since myunion is not a declared variable. Instead, you would need an actual instance of the union myunion, such as union myunion un; void *ptr = (void*)(&(un.character[0]));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the correct syntax. There's one gotcha you need to be aware of, however: x86 processors are [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). That means that if you deploy on an x86 platform (which is kinda likely) or any other little-endian platform, and have an integer such that:

```
int value = 0x01020304;
```

Then, your `char` array will read as follow:

```
character[0] == 04;
character[1] == 03;
character[2] == 02;
character[3] == 01;
```

In other words, the bytes will read in reverse order from memory. If you need to make your application portable across architectures with a different endianness, this will quickly get ugly.

However, if you account for this or don't plan to support architectures with a different endianness, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

```
union myunion
{ char ch[4]; };
...
union myunion u;
void *ptr = (void*)&u;
```

This code will place the address of the union variable `u` into `ptr`.